# How to find the reason for a risky test in PHPUnit

Tags: php, phpunit

From time to time I get a risky test in PHPUnit. Usually I can find the reason for a risky test. But the task can be time consuming, because I do not see any messages from PHPUnit, why a test is marked as risky. I only get something like this:

```
PHPUnit 4.4.5 by Sebastian Bergmann.

Configuration read from phpunit.xml.dist

R...................R.R...

Time: 11,91 seconds, Memory: 42,50Mb

OK, but incomplete, skipped, or risky tests!
Tests: 26, Assertions: 32, Risky: 3.
```

Is there any option to tell PHPUnit to show messages or better something like stack traces to the code causing the risky flag?
A complete list of causes for a risky test might prove helpful, too.

Comment: did you try phpunit command's verbose and debug options? -v or --verbose and --debug

Comment: No, did not try it. Well, it answers my question. With `-v` I get a short message, thanks.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

This question deserves an answer, taken from comments above.

```
phpunit -v
```

This gives a short description of the reason for the risky test

```
 -v|--verbose              Output more verbose information.
```

Comment: I want to run the phpunit test for my bundle tests in Symfony, and I have tried in the below way:

phpunit --verbose src\MyNameSpace\MyAppBundle\Tests\Controller\BadDataPostUnitTestControllerTest

but the error I am seeing :
Fatal error: Class 'Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase' not found in...where I have used it in my test class

Comment: Fortunately "verbose" doesn't really output much extra so you can always enable it.

Comment: This does not work in phpunit 10

Answer (score 11):

As of PHPUnit 5.3, the complete list of risky reasons:

- A test makes no assertions, when being strict about tests that do nothing. ([Source](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/master/src/Framework/TestResult.php#L825).)
- A test marked with `@todo`, when being strict about TODO annotations. ([Source](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/master/src/Framework/TestResult.php#L847).)
- Using a [function that operates on a resource](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/resource-operations/blob/master/src/ResourceOperations.php#L21-L667), when running a small test and being strict about resource usage. (Source: [thrown here](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/master/src/Framework/TestResult.php#L722) based on [this condition](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/master/src/Framework/TestResult.php#L653-L656).)
- Code does not close *exactly* the output buffers it opened. ([Source](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/master/src/Framework/TestCase.php#L2142).)
- Code executes methods not explicitly listed in `@covers` for the test. ([Source](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/master/src/Framework/TestResult.php#L778). A [blog post](http://www.jitsc.co.uk/blog/programming/phpunit-risky-tests/) on this scenario.)
- Code manually throws a [`PHPUnit_Framework_RiskyTestError`](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/master/src/Framework/RiskyTestError.php).
- Code manually throws a [`PHPUnit_Framework_UnintentionallyCoveredCodeError`](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/master/src/Framework/UnintentionallyCoveredCodeError.php).

Comment: Awesome! This is a very handly list!