# PHPUnit test...to run in verbose mode in Symfony

Tags: symfony, phpunit, verbose

I want to run the phpunit test for my bundle tests in Symfony, and I have tried in the below way:

> phpunit --verbose
>   src\MyNameSpace\MyAppBundle\Tests\Controller\BadDataPostUnitTestControllerTest

but the error I am seeing :
*Fatal error: Class 'Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase' not found in...where I have used it in my test class*

I am running the command from windows command prompt and running the command from Symfony root directory

I found the solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3708539/phpunit-get-message-ok-but-incomplete-or-skipped-tests-without-any-informa) and also from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30163282/how-to-find-the-reason-for-a-risky-test-in-phpunit), but when I am trying getting the error.

The composer dependency present, I have checked at composer.json file exists the below lines:

```
,
    "require-dev": {
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "~2.3",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^4.8",
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "^2.3",
        "phploc/phploc": "^2.1",
        "pdepend/pdepend": "^2.1",
        "phpmd/phpmd": "^2.2",
        "sebastian/phpcpd": "^2.0",
        "theseer/phpdox": "0.8.1.1",
        "symfony/browser-kit": "^2.7",
        "mayflower/php-codebrowser": "^1.1"     
    }
```

UPDATE:
While the --verbose one showing error, the below command is running properly:
*phpunit -c app /src/NameSpace/MyBundle/Tests/Controller/MyUnitTestControllerTest.php*

UPDATE:

The /app/phpunit.xml file:

```
<phpunit backupGlobals="false" backupStaticAttributes="false" colors="true" convertErrorsToExceptions="true" convertNoticesToExceptions="true" convertWarningsToExceptions="true" processIsolation="false" stopOnFailure="false" syntaxCheck="false" bootstrap="bootstrap.php.cache" codecoverage="true">

    <formatter type="clover" usefile="false"/>
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="EDS Console App Test Suite">
            <directory>../src/*/*Bundle/Tests</directory>
            <directory>../src/*/Bundle/*Bundle/Tests</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>

    <filter>
        <whitelist>
            <directory>../src</directory>
            <exclude>
                <directory>../src/*/*Bundle/Resources</directory>
                <directory>../src/*/*Bundle/Tests</directory>
                <directory>../src/*/Bundle/*Bundle/Resources</directory>
                <directory>../src/*/Bundle/*Bundle/Tests</directory>
            </exclude>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>

    <php>
        <server name='SERVER_PORT' value='8080' />
        <server name='SERVER_NAME' value='http://myserver.com' />
    </php>

    <logging>
        <log type="coverage-html" target="${basedir}/build/coverage" title="EDL-Console Test  Coverage" charset="UTF-8" yui="true" highlight="true" lowUpperBound="35" highLowerBound="70"/>
        <log type="coverage-clover" target="${basedir}/build/logs/clover.xml"/>
        <log type="junit" target="build/logs/junit.xml" logIncompleteSkipped="false"/>
    </logging>
</phpunit>
```

Comment: I guess that you didn't configure PHPunit  to use Composer's autoloader file, therefore PHP doesn't know how to find this class.

Comment: its already added
,
    "require-dev": {
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "~2.3",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^4.8",
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "^2.3",
        "phploc/phploc": "^2.1",
        "pdepend/pdepend": "^2.1",
        "phpmd/phpmd": "^2.2",
        "sebastian/phpcpd": "^2.0",
        "theseer/phpdox": "0.8.1.1",
        "symfony/browser-kit": "^2.7",
        "mayflower/php-codebrowser": "^1.1"  
    }

Comment: You've added PHPUnit package to Composer, while I'm talking about PHPUnit configuration. Completely different thing. It's about `phpunit.xml` file.

Comment: phpunit.xml is at /app directory with server_port, server_name, whitelist and testsuites mentioned, the normal -c mode is running properly

Comment: What about bootstrap property?

Comment: bootstrap.php.cache which is at /app directory

Comment: I know that it's there, but do you use it in your PHPUnit configuration? It would be better if you provide phpunit.xml file that you use.